# GWT java Widgets not appearing on designated div

Tags: java, gwt

I'm currently having problems with GWT and Eclipse. In my current implementation when i run > debug as > web application i don't get any widgets on my html page, even though i'm loading them to a div on the page.

In the pic you can see my folder organization on this project.
[image: folder organization of project]

And the code to all the relevant files is the following:

Anacom.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module rename-to='AnacomGWT'>

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />

<entry-point class='pt.ist.anacom.presentationserver.client.AnacomGWT' />

<source path='client' />

</module>
```

AnacomGWT.java

```
package pt.ist.anacom.presentationserver.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;

public class AnacomGWT implements EntryPoint{

private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();

private HorizontalPanel inserePanel = new HorizontalPanel();
private TextBox numBox = new TextBox();
private Button numBtn = new Button();

private HorizontalPanel smsPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
private TextArea smsText = new TextArea();
private TextBox smsBox = new TextBox();
private Button smsBtn = new Button();

private HorizontalPanel saldoPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
private TextBox saldoBox = new TextBox();
private Button saldoBtn = new Button();

private HorizontalPanel modoPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
private Label modoId = new Label();
private Button desligadoBtn = new Button();
private Button ligadoBtn = new Button();
private Button silencioBtn = new Button();
private Button ocupadoBtn = new Button();

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    // Assemble insereBox
    inserePanel.add(numBox);
    inserePanel.add(numBtn);

    //assemble smsPanel
    smsPanel.add(smsText);
    smsPanel.add(smsBox);
    smsPanel.add(smsBtn);

    //assemble saldoPanel
    saldoPanel.add(saldoBox);
    saldoPanel.add(saldoBtn);

    //assemble modoPanel
    modoPanel.add(modoId);
    modoPanel.add(desligadoBtn);
    modoPanel.add(ligadoBtn);
    modoPanel.add(silencioBtn);
    modoPanel.add(ocupadoBtn);

    //assemble mainPanel
    mainPanel.add(inserePanel);
    mainPanel.add(smsPanel);
    mainPanel.add(saldoPanel);
    mainPanel.add(modoPanel);

    RootPanel.get("contents").add(mainPanel);

    numBox.setFocus(true);
}

}
```

Anacom.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Anacom</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Anacom</h1>
<div id="contents"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and finally web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Anacom.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

When i run the application as a web application, in the link i get, i can only see the "ANACOM" that is wrapped in the  tag, and none of the panels i defined on anacomGWT.java, which should appear on the "contents" div as i'm calling with:

```
RootPanel.get("contents").add(mainPanel);
```

Anybody knows what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find any connection between your html and GWT. you are not specifying which gwt module will be used in your html page(Anacom.html.) . use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Anacom</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="anacom/anacom.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Anacom</h1>
<div id="contents"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the compiled javascript folder and  js file name in the comipiled folder. In your case its war/anacom/anacom.nocache.js . as ur file structure i can only see the folder name war/anacom/. It might be anacom/Anacom.nochache.js. Please verfiy and change this line accordingly. '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="anacom/anacom.nocache.js"></script>
'

Comment: It was indeed war/anacom/anacom.nocache.js, but still no results =(

Comment: Please verify 1 thing. Open your Anacom.html file in your eclipse. Press ctrl and click on the link anacom/anacom.nocache.js in your Anacom.html file and let me know if its opening with the Click or not.

Comment: Also run your application and view the source of your file from the browser and verify that this line is included <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="anacom/anacom.nocache.js"></script>
. It might be possible that the changes are not update on your web app server.

Comment: I tried every path possible, but still have no results... don't know what's happening =(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9998/discussion-between-user1270995-and-claudio-ribeiro)

Comment: It should work but i don't know y its not. ok you can try another way. Create new project in eclipse -> Google Web Project . Select generate Sample code then run the sample and make your changes in the provided sample. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to set the width/height of at least one of the elements/panels?

You should try one of the developer tools on your browser (native on IE/chrome, Firebug on Fx) and see what elements are actually created on the DOM. That will provide some meaningful information on your debugging.

Comment: I used chrome developer tools to see the elements but only the div is created. Nothing inside of it. I also checked on the design view, and all the widgets have width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Is your browser support for Javascript enabled?